# Math function using multiple matching criteria

Tags: r

I'm new to this but I'm pretty sure this question hasn't been answered, or I'm just not good at searching....

I would like to subtract the values in multiple rows from a particular row based on matching columns and values. My actual data will be a large matrix with >5000 columns, eaching needing to be subtracted by a blank value that matches the a value in a factor column.

Here is an example data table:

```
        c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
    r1  A   1   2   3   aa
    r2  B   2   3   4   bb
    r3  C   3   4   5   aa
    r4  D   4   1   6   bb
    r5  Blank   2   3   4   aa
    r6  Blank   3   4   5   bb
```

I would like to subtract the c2,c3,and c4 values of c1 ="Blank" row from A,B,and C using the c5 factor to define which Blank values are used (aa or bb). I would like the "Blank" values to be subtracted from all rows sharing c5 info.
(i know this is confusing to describe)

So the results would look like this:

```
        c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
    r1  A   -1  -1  -1  aa
    r2  B   -1  -1  -1  bb
    r3  C   1   1   1   aa
    r4  D   1   -3  1   bb
```

I've seen the ddply function work for doing something like this with a single column, but I wasn't able to expand that to perform this task for multiple columns. I'm a noob though...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested for all possible cases, but should give you an idea:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
r1  A   1   2   3   aa
r2  B   2   3   4   bb
r3  C   3   4   5   aa
r4  D   4   1   6   bb
r5  Blank   2   3   4   aa
r6  Blank   3   4   5   bb", header = T)

library(data.table)
# separate dataset into two
dt <- data.table(df, key = "c5")
dt.blank <- dt[c1 == "Blank"]
dt <- dt[c1 != "Blank"]

# merge into resulting dataset 
dt.res <- dt[dt.blank]

# update each column
columns.count <- ncol(dt)
for(i in 2:(columns.count-1)) {
  dt.res[[i]] <- dt.res[[i]] - dt.res[[i + columns.count]]
}

# > dt.res
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5  i.c1 i.c2 i.c3 i.c4
# 1:  A -1 -1 -1 aa Blank    2    3    4
# 2:  C  1  1  1 aa Blank    2    3    4
# 3:  B -1 -1 -1 bb Blank    3    4    5
# 4:  D  1 -3  1 bb Blank    3    4    5
```

Comment: I converted back to a data.frame (_dt.res2 <- data.frame(dt.res)_) so I could remove the "i" columns. Thank you Bulat!

Answer (score 0):

First split your data, since there's no reason you have them in a single data structure. Then apply the function:

```
# recreate your data
df <- data.frame(rbind(c(1:3, "aa"), c(2:4, "bb"), c(3:5, "aa"), c(4,1,6, "bb"), c(2:4, "aa"), c(3:5, "bb")))
df[,1:3] <- apply(df[,1:3], 2, as.integer)

# split it
blank1 <- df[5,]
blank2 <- df[6,]
df <- df[1:4,]

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df[i,4] == "aa") {df[i,1:3] <- df[i,1:3] - blank1[1:3]}
  else                 {df[i,1:3] <- df[i,1:3] - blank2[1:3]}
}
```

There are a few different was to run the loop, including vectorizing. But this suffices. I'd also argue that there's no reason to keep the labels "aa" v "bb" in the initial data structure either, which would make this simpler; but it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alex! The reason I have the aa bb is because my actual data set has many many different levels for which I'd like to perform this task. I have considered separating all of the Blanks from the other rows, but it would be great if I didn't need to code each match individually...

Comment: @Alex Your comment doesn't clearly clarify your question for me. Implementing a more general search strategy is certainly easy enough; but you need to provide a clear question in your OP.